# Android AlarmManager at Boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, boot, intentservice

I am using an AlarmManager to start a service that runs every minute. However, I am getting the "The application blabla has stopped unexpectedly." warning dialog with Force Close button when I turn on the device. I do not know what the error is because the only debugging option I have is with WIFI and the IP of the connection changes every time I reboot the device.

The service runs fine without the boot.

Here is my BroadcastReceiver running under the application:

```
    public class FPBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

        Intent bootintent = new Intent(context, FPService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, bootintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long nextUpdateTimeMillis = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
        Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
        nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

        AlarmManager FPAlarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        FPAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), nextUpdateTimeMillis, pi);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/pc"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service android:name=".FPService" />

    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="mypackage.FPBootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name=".CF_Aachen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Anything wrong you see that I am doing wrong with these?

**UPDATE:** Managed to debug the boot and I am getting AndroidRuntime(2781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver mypackage.FPBootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.FPBootReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Comment: Did you check the Logcat output?

Comment: Please read above. I cannot because it is a WIFI debugging and IP address changes with every boot. Is there a way to send this BOOT intent without having to turn off the device?

Comment: How can you not get the logcat output if you can debug the app?

Comment: As I said above, I cannot debug at boot because the IP address changes with every boot and my only option for debugging is over WIFI. Now I managed to find a command line to send the BOOT_COMPLETED intent and I can see the Logcat. Please see the update above.

Comment: In your manifest change mypackage.FPBootReceiver to test.aachen.FPBootReceiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my BroadcastReceiver class under the same class of my Activity. That's why it was unable to find it.

I created a seperate class file in mypackage and created the class there and then it was solved.

Thanks to all who advised.

Answer (score 2):

Android system can not see your Receiver, check your path unless your full package is actually "mypackage". You ether need to make it ".mypackage.FPBootReceiver" or specify the full path.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. Something similar to what you are saying.